# How to add autocomplete searchbox in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, search, autocomplete, submit

I am trying to implement autocomplete  feature in one of my applications. I am using angucomplete. But it is not accepting local-data which is an array!.Also I want to submit the text that is typed in the search box if it is not present in the searched data. Any help could be appreciated. Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right road. Use angucomplete-alt (https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt). It accepts array data. Use "override-suggestions" attribute to submit your own text.

You can also try to use angular material (material.angularjs.org), but it less able to customize.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using angucomplete-alt, But I am not able to add the text which is not in the dropdown. And also my search data is an array which is stored in a variable in my controller, It is not a result of ajax call

Comment: Thanks, But my arrays doesn't have any objects in it. It has set of items. SO, there I can't define title-field and search-fields. How can I bind array values in this case?

Comment: Try to stay these fields empty, or convert your array of values to array of objects

Comment: I left these fields empty but It was not useful :(